# Failed (exit code: 1) when trying to restore DB from a .tar file in pgAdmin4

Tags: postgresql, backup, restore, errors, pgadmin-4

I'm been trying to restore my database and I'm getting an Exit error code 1. The database I'm trying to restore is SuperMart_DB.tar, but every time I get the same error message.

[image]

I have seen previous recommendation where it was mentioned to uncheck data option from Restore options.By default data section is in NO state but still I'm getting the same error.
[image]

I'm new to SQL and currently going through online course but unable to proceed further. I've also completely rebooted the computer several times since then but still the problem persists. Please help.

Comment: Import it with `pg_restore` on the command line and read the error message.